# Has ESlint a rule about blank line before the first statement in function?

Tags: javascript, code-formatting, eslint

Due ESLint I found a rule *newline-before-return* about empty line before return statements. But did not see a rule about empty line before the first statement in function. F.e.:

```
function (a) {

    var b = +a;
}
```

Has ESlint a rule about this? If it has, what is the name this rule?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [padded-blocks](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/padded-blocks) rule allows you to require newlines at the start and end of blocks, including function bodies. In addition to function bodies, it also covers the bodies of `if` statements, `for` and `while` loops, and other block-like structures, which you may or may not want.

Try pasting the following code in the [demo](http://eslint.org/demo) to see if it works for you:

```
/* eslint padded-blocks: "error" */
function foo(bar) {

    if (bar) {

        foo();

    }

}
```

If you only want to check function bodies, you could follow @Dhananjay's suggestion and edit the rule's [source code](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/d6fd0641abc55d6ae9e4f28325d42d0ea5241fa9/lib/rules/padded-blocks.js) into your own custom rule.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is such a rule available out of the box based on the list of [available rules](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/) You can try to add a custom rule for this check as explained [here](https://gist.github.com/jareware/7179093)

Answer (score 1):

Such rule is implemented in the [HAPI ESLint plugin](https://github.com/continuationlabs/eslint-plugin-hapi), installed this way:

```
npm install @hapi/eslint-plugin-hapi --save-dev
// Add in your `.eslintrc`
{
  plugins: [
    '@hapi/eslint-plugin-hapi',
  ],
  rules: {
    '@hapi/hapi/scope-start': ['error'],
  },
};

}
```

Or you may use it as part of [HAPI ESLint config](https://github.com/continuationlabs/eslint-config-hapi).
Mind, that [Airbnb style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#whitespace--padded-blocks) recommends against padding blocks.

Comment: It works if you don't want to use the --fix option of lint.