# How to allow one white line after an opening brace in ESLint-prettier?

Tags: eslint, prettier-eslint

My typescript code is setup with eslint-prettier. I'd like to have the option of formatting my functions to look like this:

```
function Name(){

    // First line
    ...
}
```

... rather than always having to look like this:

```
function Name(){
    // First line
    ...
}
```

Is there a setting within prettier and/or ESLint to enable this?

Comment: Not specifically functions, but the closest default ESLint rule would be [`padded-blocks`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padded-blocks)

Comment: Found a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39098773/2758250